# Package tm stop-word parameter

Tags: r, nlp

I am trying to filter stop-words from the following documents using package `tm`.

```
library(tm)
documents <- c("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "i am the walrus")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(documents))
matrix <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(stopwords=TRUE))
```

However, when I run this code I still get the following in the `DocumentTermMatrix`.

```
colnames(matrix)
[1] "brown"  "dog"    "fox"    "jumps"  "lazy"   "over"   "quick"  "the"    "walrus"
```

"The" is listed as a stop-word in the list that package `tm` uses. Am I doing something wrong regarding the `stopwords` parameter, or is this a bug in the `tm` package?

**EDIT:** I contacted Ingo Feinerer and he noted that it is technically not a bug:

> User-provided options are processed first, and then all remaining
>   options. Hence stopword removal is done before tokenization (as
>   already written by Vincent Zoonekynd on stackoverflow.com) which gives
>   exactly your result.

Therefore, the solution is to explicitly list the default tokenizing option prior to the `stopwords` parameter, for example:

```
library(tm)
documents <- c("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog", "i am the walrus")
corpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(documents))
matrix <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus,control=list(tokenize=scan_tokenizer,stopwords=TRUE))
colnames(matrix)
```

Comment: Thanks for the questions and answers...although none of them worked at all in my issue.  Seems like stopwords in TM is just a headache at this point in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug: you may want to report it to the package author(s). The `termFreq` function applies various filters to the texts, but not always in the right order. In your example, the code attempts to remove the stopwords before tokenization, i.e., before the text is cut into words -- it should be after, once we know what the words are.

Comment: How would I make the `control` list apply to words once they're tokenized?

Comment: Until the bug is fixed, the easiest workaraound is Sacha's answer. Adding the tokenizer to the control list (before the stopwords: the order is important) may also work, but it looks needlessly complicated.

Comment: In my opinion it's much simpler: you are keeping all manipulations in one line of code rather than spreading them out over several. This makes it simpler to read which transformations are being applied in a quick glance (particularly when you are applying several transformations).

Answer (score 4):

You could also try removing the stopwords from the corpus before you create the term matrix.

```
text_corpus <- tm_map(text_corpus, removeWords, stopwords("english"))
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(text_corpus)
```

This usually works for me.

Answer (score 2):

A quick fix would be to run this afterwards:

```
matrix <- matrix[,!colnames(matrix)%in%stopwords()]
```